# Why the javascript console does not throw error on creating object recursively?

Tags: javascript, recursion

```
var main =  function() {
    this.first = this;
}
console.log(new main().first);
```

The code is here :
Object is creating recursively ,I didnot understand why the console not throwing any error.
Please tell me if there is any concept behind this.

Comment: there's no reason for it to throw...

Comment: it's not clear what you are asking here.  This code doesn't show any recursion, nor does it show anything that would cause an error to be thrown.

Comment: if you were to JSON.stringify it it would throw then, but the console is smart enough to avoid that.

Comment: Re-cursing but only twice...Or rather once!.

Comment: What do you mean by "creating object recursively"? The fact that an object contains a reference to itself? That is allowed.

Comment: @forgivenson i think the OP meant self referencing.

Answer (score 1):

You are making it circular (not recursive) with this:

```
this.first = this
```

It's the same as if you do:

```
var obj = {}
obj.first = obj
```

`obj.first` will reference `obj`. That in javascript is like saying `obj.first` is `obj`. Really the javascript engine isn't creating infinite objects, just an object that has a reference to itself.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't throw an error simply because the value of a property of an object is allowed to be a reference to that object. You don't have any actual recursion here.

You'd only get an error if, for example, you wrote a function to recursively crawl down through the properties of the object, but that would be because you had too many functions on the stack and the self reference would only be a factor that led to that.

Answer (score 0):

There's no recursion here.  What you have is a self reference (where one object stores a property that refers to itself).

Your code does not throw because `console.log()` is smart enough to handle self references.  It doesn't infinite loop just because of a self reference as it is coded to specifically handle that situation.